# How to disable java.util.logging in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, java.util.logging

I found that my web application 3-rd part library uses java.util.logging and writes many messages in catalina.out.
Does it possible redirect it to other file(s)?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be the bridge java.util.logging (which is awful) to a more sensible API, and then configure your logging from there.

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) provides a [JUL-to-SLF4J bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j), which can do this fairly easily.